# Unable to Display Toast in Fragment

Tags: java, android, xml, fragment

Here I have added the Java And Xml File In which I just want to display a Toast when the user clicks on the button.

This is just to check whether the Fragment is working or not.

Here onClickListener is not working for me in the Fragment. Even setText on TextView was not working when I tried. I Think there is sometihing problem with the components or some problem between the connection of java and xml file

**Setting.java**

```
    package com.example.dell.jsonexp;

    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.content.SharedPreferences;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
    import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    public class setting extends Fragment {
        BackgroundTask b;
    String e;
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View RootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.setting, container, false);

            final Button logout= (Button) RootView.findViewById(R.id.logout);
            logout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Button Pressed",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                }
            });

            return inflater.inflate(R.layout.setting, container, false);
        }


    }
```

**setting.xml**

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/logout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
            android:text="Logout" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a `Fragment` you cant access view components in `onCreateView()` method, You have to `Override` `onViewCreated()` method.
Please update your code as below.

```
    package com.example.dell.jsonexp;

    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.content.SharedPreferences;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
    import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    public class setting extends Fragment {
        BackgroundTask b;
        String e;

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            return inflater.inflate(R.layout.setting, container, false);
        }

        @Override
        public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

            Button logout= (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.logout);
            logout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Button Pressed",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                }
            });
        }

    }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You are setting a click listener to a button that is never shown.

You need to return the rootView instead of inflating another view.

```
return rootView;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to return

```
return RootView;
```

and for the **Toast** you have to write

```
getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Whatever you want here", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```